# How to create a logic in pandas to create a new column based on existing values in other column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In this problem, I am trying to understand when an alert should be generated based on 'value'.

If previous 5 values are above 10, then an alert is created. The alert continues to stay active till the value goes below 7.5. Now, once the alert is no longer active and it reaches a stage where previous 5 values are above 10, then an alert is created again.

How can I create the column to identify if it 'is an alert' or not using pandas?

Appreciate all the help!

```
Value Is Previous 5      Is the value greater        Is it an Alert?
        Rolling               than 7.5?
     Greater than 10?       
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  Yes                  Yes                       Yes
11  Yes                  Yes    
11  Yes                  Yes    
8   No                   Yes    
9   No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  Yes                  Yes    
8   No                   Yes    
9   No                   Yes    
6   No                    No    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  No                   Yes    
11  Yes                  Yes                       Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NUM_PREV_ROWS = 5
PREV_5_THRESHOLD = 10.0
PREV_THRESHOLD = 7.5
df = pd.DataFrame([11,11,11,11,11,11,11,8,9,11,11,11,11,11,8,9,6,11,11,11,11,11], columns=['value'])

df['prev>10'] = df['value']>PREV_5_THRESHOLD
df['prev5>10'] = df['prev>10'].rolling(NUM_PREV_ROWS).sum()
df['prev>7.5'] = df['value']>PREV_THRESHOLD 

alert = False
alert_series = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1]['prev5>10']==NUM_PREV_ROWS:
        alert = True
    if row[1]['prev>7.5']==False:
        alert = False
    alert_series.append(alert)

df['alert'] = alert_series
```

```
print(df)

    value  prev>10  prev5>10  prev>7.5  alert
0      11     True       NaN      True  False
1      11     True       NaN      True  False
2      11     True       NaN      True  False
3      11     True       NaN      True  False
4      11     True       5.0      True   True
5      11     True       5.0      True   True
6      11     True       5.0      True   True
7       8    False       4.0      True   True
8       9    False       3.0      True   True
9      11     True       3.0      True   True
10     11     True       3.0      True   True
11     11     True       3.0      True   True
12     11     True       4.0      True   True
13     11     True       5.0      True   True
14      8    False       4.0      True   True
15      9    False       3.0      True   True
16      6    False       2.0     False  False
17     11     True       2.0      True  False
18     11     True       2.0      True  False
19     11     True       3.0      True  False
20     11     True       4.0      True  False
21     11     True       5.0      True   True
```